# simulate AngularJS button click in c# uwp app

Tags: c#, angularjs, button, webview, uwp

I am trying to create an app that automatically logs me into a webpage.
The page is not mine so I cannot see the code behind it.
http://pcc.magister.net (the page after the first notification screen)

Now I've managed to insert the username and password but I just cannot seem to be capable of triggering a click on the button in the page. I get as far as this :

```
var functionString = string.Format(@"document.getElementsByClassName('primary-btn ripple')[0].click();");
await Display.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
```

But I am getting nothing but errors. 'System.Exception' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll and a 0x80020101 event that is a general javascript error.

The button in DOM explorer looks like this :

```
<mg-button is-loading="$ctrl.isLoading" caption="doorgaan">
<button class="primary-button ripple" type="submit" ng-class="{'active': $ctrl.isLoading}">
</button></mg-button>
```

Anybody smarter than me who sees what I'm doing wrong here ?

Here is a minimal c# :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at    https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Display.Navigate(new Uri("http://pcc.magister.net/"));
    }
    private async void NewPageLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        string functionString = "";
        if (Display.Source.AbsolutePath.ToString() == "/account/login")
        {
            functionString = String.Format("document.getElementById('username').innerText = 'testuser'");
            try
            {
                await Display.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
            }
            catch
            {
                //
            }
            functionString = string.Format("document.getElementsByClassName('primary-btn ripple')[0].click();");
            try
            {
                await Display.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
            }
            catch (Exception ezz)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("There was an exception!" + ezz);
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And a minimal XAML :

```
<Page
x:Class="Test.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Test"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="mainGrid">
    <WebView Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="Display" NavigationCompleted="NewPageLoaded"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: You're using the wrong class name, the correct class name is `primary-button ripple`, not `primary-btn ripple`

Comment: F&*&*((*   You are right :-)

Comment: Ok, now I had the whole thing working. Updated to Fall Creators Update, and now the app gives me 0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Blocked by Content Security Policy. I build the app in Creators update published in store and loaded the app in 2 VMs. One running Creators update, the other Fall Creators update. The one in Fall Creators update fails, the other one works. Any ideas what changed in Fall Update ?